# hotmail isn't receiving mail from my server

Tags: smtp, email

Hotmail is block all mails (not send to Junk, it really block!) send from my VPS server (even if I send directly from roundcube, for instance). I checked all configs and seems that all is ok. Works to gmail and yahoo normally. These are my tests:

- **Mail Troubleshooter:** example@hotmail.com lookuphost via mx1.hotmail.com [a lot IPs] MX=5: **OK**
- **mxtoolbox.net**: no blacklisted (0/98): **OK**
- **PHPMailer**: Connection: opened to example.com:587 [...] 250 **OK**
- **Port25 verifier**:

  - **SPF check**: pass;
  - **DomainKeys check**: neutral
  - **DKIM check**: pass
  - **Sender-ID check**: pass
  - **SpamAssassin check**: ham (-2.0)
- Registered on ReturnPath, SenderScore (97), SenderBase, SNDS and JMRP, dedicated IP;
- Reverse DNS return `example.myprovider.com` (maybe it can be the problem?);
- Valid sender auth on account;
- Tried on two hotmails differents accounts;

*Tell me if I can do additional tests to increase the number of information.*

Comment: Is there any relevant information in the maillog or any bounce messages that get returned to you?

Comment: Seems normal: http://pastebin.com/iQuscbSq

Comment: Message is indeed queued at the hotmail end, for further debugging you need support from an admin at Hotmail.